# Is there any alternative for issubset() for list in python. all I want is to return a bool True if list1 is subset of list2 else False

Tags: python, list, set, subset

Is there any alternative for issubset() for list in python. all I want is to return a bool True if list1 is subset of list2 else False.

So that
{
`if list1.ABC(list2)`
}
will return True if all the elements of list1 is already there in list2, else False

Comment: Why is issubset not good? It returns True and False

Answer (score 1):

## all()

You can use the [all()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_all.asp) function which returns True if all items in an iterable are true, otherwise it returns False. You would use it like this :

```
list1 = {1, 5, 6}
list2 = {77, 1, 4, 5, 6}

x = all(el in list2 for el in list1) 
print(x)
```

The all() returns True

### Explanation

```
el in list2 for el in list1
```

This iterable will go trough all elements in list1 and check if they are in list2. It return True if the element is in both lists and false if not. As list1 has 3 elements it will run 3 times. The all() function just checks if all of the 3 rounds return True or not. So it returns True if all are True and False if one or more are False.

Comment: You literarily just copied all my response??

Comment: I'm new here so took me some time to write it, i started some 15 minutes ago. Your answer was not visible for me at the time. I tried to explain the code as well. Sorry if it seemed like I took your work, I would never do that.

Comment: Well since , you gave an explanation, i will make delete mine then. welcome to SO